# getRunningAppProcesses() returns processes that were destroyed

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I am using the following snippet to check whether applications that I `finish()`ed are indeed no longer running:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> procList = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo proc : procList)
    Log.d(TAG, proc.processName);
}
```

To my dismay, some applications that I `finish()`ed (in their Activity.onCreate(), even before they had a chance to launch anything), are still listed there.

Why?

LogCat shows that these applications' `onDestroy()` **was definitely** called.

What does it take to truly remove an application from that list?

Is `killProcess()` my only recourse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an area of confusion for many, as can be seen in [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108830/android-does-ondestroy-or-finish-actually-kill-the-activity).

In fact, even [this book](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449390501/Main_Building_Blocks.html) from a respected source such as O'Reilly can confuse matters by suggesting that the *Destroyed* state can mean "killed" and that it can be reached from either `onDestroy()` or *process killed*:

[image]

IMHO, that O'Reilly state diagram is flawed and doesn't reflect the full behavior of the system as the "official" diagram does:

[image]

Analyzing this diagram, one can conclude that  `onDestroy()` never automatically leads to *App process killed*. I believe this answers your first question.

As for you second question, the answer is **yes**: If you really want to totally kill your application's process (why would you want to do that?), then your only recourse is [killProcess()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#killProcess%28int%29).